# Send me an alert or email when the server shuts down

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

Is there a way I can get my minecraft server to alert me if it shuts down? Either via an Email or SMS? I'd even be willing to accept an automated phone call.

I run my server using a .sh script

Comment: I'd guess you need to go for a cronjob, don't think any minecraft plugin (by itself) can afford to do such actions

Comment: If you control your server via a `.bat` or `.sh` script, you can add a mailer or SMS function after you invoke `java` to run your server. Whenever the server stops, your custom action will take effect.

Comment: I actually do have it run through an .sh script. how would i do the mailer function?

Comment: The simplest would be to use your system mail command, which is either `mail` or `mailx`, if installed. For example, `echo "I stopped" | mail -s "Your Server" you@youremailaddress.com` But that also assumes that your Linux system is set up to relay mail messages, which is a completely different subject matter best researched on its own.

Comment: This might be a possible starting point: https://github.com/trgwii/TeMiCross

Comment: Or alternatively you just put ` && <command>` behind your server start command. I think that should trigger once the server no longer runs, but I'm not sure.